# É errado utilizar o verbo em diferentes posições em uma frase?

Tags: sintaxe

O que estou procurando é se (exemplo) "Quantos livros a Biblioteca de Babel possui?" e "Quantos livros possui a Biblioteca de Babel?" têm diferença ou se uma está errada ou não e que área é essa no Português?

Comment: português não leva maiúscula.

Comment: @Lambie pode levar.

Comment: @bad_coder Em geral, as línguas não levam maiúsculas: Ele fala português e alemào. E certamente aqui não levaria.

Answer (score 1):

Ambas as forma são possíveis e serão entendidas da mesma forma. Há quem dê preferência a uma em relação à outra, é muito variável.

Comment: Me atrevo a dizer que em pt-BR a 1a versão normalmente soa mais natural.

Comment: E tem razão em afirmar isso, a segunda opção é mais comum em Portugal!